# Performing calculations on table cells

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a php script which generates a pricelist in a table. Example of a generated table:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>100</th>     
    <th>+100</th>           
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
           <th>A5<span>210x148</span></th>
           <td>€65.00</td>
           <td>€8</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <th>A4<span>297x210</span></th>
           <td>€75.00</td>
           <td>€16</td>
        </tr>       
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Basically what I want to do is make a button to add VAT. So: take the values from the price cells, add 21% and replace the original value. If the button is clicked again, it restarts.

My issue is that I am not familiar with jquery and can not figure out how to extract and rewrite the values per cel. I can get the effect I want if I add an id to a cell, however I can't seem to figure out how to do it for all the cells. Another thing I can't get working is stripping away the currency sign to do the calculation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you should be doing that calculation on the client side.  It would probably be better if that was all provided during generation, with just a way to show/hide it.

Comment: +1, ajax the table and setting a `?vat=hidden` flag would be better

Comment: Hi Maikelv, if you find the response useful, mark one as answer.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to give those 'price' cells a class name

```
<td class='price'>
```

and then loop through that collection of elements:

```
$('price').each(function(index) {
     vat = $(this).text().replace("$", "") * 1.21;
     $(this).text() = vat;
  });
```

Untested but hopefully it communicates the idea.

Comment: `<td 'class=price'>` huh? Did you mean `<td class='price'>`

Comment: Fixed the class name :-), you could use `parseFloat` instead, this would mean you won't have to guess what currency / format they have it in.

Comment: i just read more carefully and realized that we're not trying to sum them (i should never SO before my first coffee.)

Comment: @ILMV: *parseFloat()* isn't a locale dependent function, it looks for the floating point grammar at the start of a string.  This means you might need to check for a comma as the decimal separator.  I tend to find *Number()* or unary *+* more useful than *parseFloat()* for all sorts of reasons.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a class to EVERY table cell where you'll have the price to compute VAT like

```
<td class='priceCell'>
```

and then do something like on the first press button

```
$('priceCell').each(function(index) {
     $(this).text() = calculateVAT($(this).text());
  });
```

Where calculateVAT is a function javascript who calculates VAT. As this solution performs float point calculation on a number that could be rounded, another possible elegant solution is to add an hidden column with VAT-added totals and the button just switch between the two columns

Comment: I like the hidden column solution, since it allows me to do most of the programming in PHP. Let me try that...

Comment: A hidden column is actually a very good idea, saves calculating it all client side :-)